# Trying to create some login validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the code of my authentication modal. Please, advise on how I should change my JavaScript to prevent empty login submit.

1. The login modal:

```html
                         <div class="cd-user-modal"> 
            <!-- this is the entire modal form,
            including the background -->
     <div class="cd-user-modal-container"> 
             <!-- this is the container wrapper -->
   <ul class="cd-switcher">
    <li><a href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">New account</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div id="cd-login"> <!-- log in form -->
    <form class="cd-form">
     <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-email" 
                               for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"
                          id="signin-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
     </p>

     <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-password" 
                               for="signin-password">Password</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"
                         id="signin-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
      <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
     </p>

     <p class="fieldset">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
      <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
     </p>

     <p class="fieldset">
      <input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Login">
     </p>
    </form>
    
    <p class="cd-form-bottom-message">
                  <a href="#0">Forgot your password?</a></p>
    <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
   </div> <!-- cd-login -->

   <div id="cd-signup"> <!-- sign up form -->
    <form class="cd-form">
     <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-username" 
                               for="signup-username">Username</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"
                        id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
     </p>

     <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-email" 
                               for="signup-email">E-mail</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"
                           id="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
     </p>

     <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-password" 
                               for="signup-password">Password</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"
                        id="signup-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
      <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
     </p>

     <p class="fieldset">
      <input type="checkbox" id="accept-terms">
      <label for="accept-terms">I agree to the <a                                       href="#0">Terms</a></label>
     </p>

     <p class="fieldset">
      <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit"
                               value="Create account">
     </p>
    </form>

    <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> 
   </div> <!-- cd-signup -->

   <div id="cd-reset-password"> <!-- reset password form -->
    <p class="cd-form-message">Lost your password? Please enter your
             email address. You will receive a link to create a new password.</p>

    <form class="cd-form">
     <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="reset-email">
                          E-mail</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"
                               id="reset-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
     </p>

     <p class="fieldset">
      <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit"
                               value="Reset password">
     <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a>
     </p>
    </form>

    <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Back to log-in</a>             </p>
   </div> <!-- cd-reset-password -->
   
  </div> <!-- cd-user-modal-container -->
      </div> <!-- cd-user-modal -->
```

2. The piece in the Javascript file that I'm trying to edit:

```js
//EDIT THIS - it's just to show error messages 
 formLogin.find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  formLogin.find('input[type="email"]').toggleClass('has-error').next('span').toggleClass('is-visible');
 });
 formSignup.find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  formSignup.find('input[type="email"]').toggleClass('has-error').next('span').toggleClass('is-visible');
 });
```

Comment: And your question was?

Comment: LOL Scott... thanks for pointing out I missed asking anything... I already edited the question

Comment: That's really not what SO is for. If you are having a specific problem or have a specific question with the code, please ask, but we don't just write code or explain everything, that's too time consuming and leads to posts that never end.

Answer (score 1):

I was taught to do things a little differently than they way you're going about it.

If I have a form that looks kind of like this:

```
<form id="form"  action="welcome/submit" method="post">
    name:
    <span class="warning" id="warning_0">please enter your name >>></span>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    email:
    <span class="warning" id="warning_1">please enter your email address >>></span>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">


    phone:
    <span class="warning" id="warning_2">please enter your phone >>></span>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">

    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="contact_sent">
</form>
```

The action attribute in the form is where I'm sending the posted data. In my case a PHP file.

I hide the class 'warning' with CSS:

```
.warning{
    color:red;
    display:none;}
```

And then with Javascript - jQuery in my case - I evaluate the data before sending by triggering a function on the form's submit:

```
<script>
    $('#form').submit(function(event) {

    var input = [];
    input[0] = $("#name").val();
    input[1] = $("#email").val();
    input[2] = $("#phone").val();

    var ready = true;

    for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(input[i].length < 1){
            $('#warning_'+i).fadeIn('slow');
            ready = false;
        }
        if(input[i].length > 0){
            $('#warning_'+i).fadeOut('fast');
        }
    }

    return ready;

    });
</script>
```

Here's the cool thing, if the click function returns false then the posted data doesn't go through to the php file.  The warnings that need to be displayed are turned visible.  But if everything is filled out then true is returned and off it goes to your server.

I realize that is a little different than how you're going about things but from going through what you have, I think you're making it harder than it needs to be.  But it could also be that you're trying to achieve something more complicated that I'm not quite understanding.